# Webpack devtool has no effect whatsoever in development mode

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I'm quite confused about how webpack's `devtool` setting works in webpack 4.41.5.  [The documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) offers an entire list of different ways that source maps can be configured, with different trade-offs.  While building in production mode these seem to have various effects, but in development mode, there is no difference between these settings whatsoever.  Here's an example:

entry.js:

```
// trivial entry point
console.log('hello world');
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = [
    false, 'eval', 'eval-cheap-source-map', 'eval-cheap-module-source-map', 'eval-source-map',
    'cheap-source-map', 'cheap-module-source-map', 'inline-cheap-source-map', 'inline-cheap-module-source-map',
    'source-map', 'inline-source-map', 'hidden-source-map', 'nosources-source-map'
].map(tool => ({
    entry:   './entry.js',
    devtool: tool,
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: `./[name]-${tool}.js`
    },
}));
```

Here's the output of the build:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/webpack -d
< lots of output >
$ sha1sum main-*.js
a479a5b3b67961d9ec19dbcbf2b8c67a80c1ec90  main-cheap-module-source-map.js
a479a5b3b67961d9ec19dbcbf2b8c67a80c1ec90  main-cheap-source-map.js
a479a5b3b67961d9ec19dbcbf2b8c67a80c1ec90  main-eval-cheap-module-source-map.js
a479a5b3b67961d9ec19dbcbf2b8c67a80c1ec90  main-eval-cheap-source-map.js
a479a5b3b67961d9ec19dbcbf2b8c67a80c1ec90  main-eval.js
a479a5b3b67961d9ec19dbcbf2b8c67a80c1ec90  main-eval-source-map.js
a479a5b3b67961d9ec19dbcbf2b8c67a80c1ec90  main-false.js
a479a5b3b67961d9ec19dbcbf2b8c67a80c1ec90  main-hidden-source-map.js
a479a5b3b67961d9ec19dbcbf2b8c67a80c1ec90  main-inline-cheap-module-source-map.js
a479a5b3b67961d9ec19dbcbf2b8c67a80c1ec90  main-inline-cheap-source-map.js
a479a5b3b67961d9ec19dbcbf2b8c67a80c1ec90  main-inline-source-map.js
a479a5b3b67961d9ec19dbcbf2b8c67a80c1ec90  main-nosources-source-map.js
a479a5b3b67961d9ec19dbcbf2b8c67a80c1ec90  main-source-map.js
```

They're all *exactly* the same and include this:

```
eval("console.log('hello world');\n//# sourceURL=[module]\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoiLi9lbnRyeS5qcy5qcyIsInNvdXJjZXMiOlsid2VicGFjazovLy8uL2VudHJ5LmpzPzA5OGYiXSwic291cmNlc0NvbnRlbnQiOlsiY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ2hlbGxvIHdvcmxkJyk7XG4iXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiJBQUFBOyIsInNvdXJjZVJvb3QiOiIifQ==\n//# sourceURL=webpack-internal:///./entry.js\n");
```

They obviously all include a source map, even when explicitely requesting not to include one (main-false.js) and they all include the full source even when requested not to do so (main-nosources-source-map.js, the decoded base64 string contains the source).

Clearly the `devtool` setting is not one that is supposed to only have an effect in production mode, since many of the options are labeled as *production: no* in the documentation.

Did I seriously misunderstand what this setting is supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing webpack CLI the `-d` [1] flag which equates (expands) to the following:

```
--debug --devtool cheap-module-eval-source-map --output-pathinfo
```

Hence you are overwriting each configuration's `devtool` config property value with `"cheap-module-eval-source-map"`.

Try running your command without the `-d` flag, i.e. just `node_modules/.bin/webpack`.

[1] https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#shortcuts

Comment: Ooh how stupid of me... I thought `-d` is short for `--mode=development` since `-p` is short for `--mode=production`. Running without `-d` doesn't work, since it defaults to a production build, which is not what I want. So I really want to run just with `--mode=development`.